# Ruby on Rails hangs during HTTP request from Python script

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, docker, python-requests, dockerpy

I'm writing a web application in Ruby on Rails where users can write python code in a web editor and execute it in an docker environment on the server. I've written a simple python code that creates a docker container:

```
import docker
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if(len(sys.argv) == 2):
        token = sys.argv[1]
        client = docker.from_env()
        res = client.containers.run('openql','python3 /home/pythonwrapper.py '+token)

else:
    print("Requires one parameter")
```

As you can see it creates a docker container using the image openql and execute a simple python script inside. If a user press the execute button in the web editor Ruby on Rails executes this script by using the this command: `system("python","script.py","<TOKEN>")` So far so good, this works all fine.

However, there is a problem executing the `pythonwrapper.py` inside the docker container. I'm using python's requests library for requesting the files written by the user to execute them inside the docker container. The code looks like this:

```
# Request all the available assets, it does not download the content of the files. 
# Downloading the content of the files is done in a later request
url = rails_url+"allAssets/"+token
res = requests.get(url)
#Convert bytes into string
content = str(res.content, 'utf8')
```

Looks pretty simple, but the whole ruby on rails webserver hangs during this request. And the strange thing is that it all works fine if I first executes this script manually from the console after restarting the server.

The only thing I get from the Rails console if this:

```
Started GET "/allAssets/123" for 10.0.2.15 at 2017-08-02 10:24:59 +0200
```

When I quit the webserver for a restart, Ruby on Rails shows the following logs:

[Screenshot console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe3Lg.png)

And then nothing. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be running the container in background i guess.

```
    res = client.containers.run('openql','python3 /home/pythonwrapper.py '+token, detach=True)
```

This will make sure that your server is not stuck till it waits for the container to complete and finish the command it is executing

Comment: Great, didn't think of this, sometimes a solution can be so simple. Thank you